# App Engine Maven compilation error

Tags: java, json, maven, google-app-engine

I am trying to deploy an application on to Google App Engine. 
when I execute `mvn clean install` I get this error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.
1:compile (default-compile) on project testproject: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /D:/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.27/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.27/demos/testproject/src/main/java/com/danter/google/auth/GoogleAuthHelper.java:[13,42] package com.google.api.client.json.jackson does not exist
```

I added the following dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-client-java6</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.0-beta</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.0-beta</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson2</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.0-beta</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: i did not add  'google-http-client-jackson' what is its 'groupid' and 'artifactid'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the library [`google-http-client-jackson`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.http-client/google-http-client-jackson/1.20.0). Add it to your POM like this:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.0-beta</version>
</dependency>
```

As a side note, I suggest you introduce a property holding the `1.12.0-beta` version. If you upgrade in the future, you won't have to change every dependency but just the property.